# how to fix mongoose array in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i'm trying to push objects into my mongodb db.
I'm able to view said data when pushed in my console.log. but they arent pushed into the db at all.

Below is my app.js code..

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email : String,
    password: String,
    selectedPet : [String]
});



userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.post("/prototype",(req, res) =>{
    var animalSelected = [];
     animalSelected.push = req.body.selectedPet;

  console.log(req.user.id, animalSelected);
  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if (foundUser){
            foundUser.selectedPet = animalSelected;
            foundUser.save(function(){
                res.redirect("/proto")
            });
        }
    }
  });
  });
```

Comment: I am not sure with your code, but you should try [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) method only and `$push` operator to push element in array. instead of find and save.

Comment: could you kindly elaborate, im just a rookie

Comment: and could you pleaseeeee kindly check this out, your opinion would be well appreciated ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375085/how-to-fix-reference-error-says-item-not-defined